# Multiple answers for a node in IBM Watson Conversation service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

How I can specify multiple answers for a specific dialog node? For example, when user asks “What is your name”, my VA should reply “My name is Alexander”, or “You can call me Alexander”, or “Friends call me Alex”.
Maybe Conversation service must return a code and application checks the code and choose a random answer from answer's db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the application node that gives the response, select advanced mode and change to this:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "My name is Alexander.",
        "You can call me Alexander", 
        "Friends call me Alex"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "random",
      "append": false
    }
  }
}
```